# React Native - SQLite configuration error

Tags: sqlite, reactjs, react-native

First off, I tried to search for questions that kind of relates to the problem that I am facing, but alas no luck at all! If this question has been answered before, please do point me to it and sorry for the inconvenience.

Coming as a Cordova developer react-native sounds like a dream coming true but I am still a noob at it and am still learning it. I installed this [SQLite plugin](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) and followed every step for android development. But when I try to run the app on a simulator I always get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-sqlite-storage'.
       > failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
```

The configurations that I did:

**settings.gradle**:

```
rootProject.name = 'todo'

include ':app'

include ':react-native-sqlite-storage'
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android')
```

**build.gradle**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        [...]
```

**MainApplication.java**:

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new SQLitePluginPackage(this),
      new MainReactPackage();
  );
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

there is another "build.gradle" file that you should config!
in your ".../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android/src/build.gradle" 
change the build version on that file too!

set it with your build.gradle that already changed!

Answer (score -1):

In your Android studio go to your SDK manager and find SDK tools tab. In there if you check the 'Show Package Details' you will find "Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1"

Install that and you are good to go :)